# How to automatically partially replace JSON properties with values from an object without token selectors

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Let's say I have a model:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FruitName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a JSON string that looks like this:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "FruitName": "Apple",
  "Currency": "USD"
}
```

Without using token selectors, how would I programmatically replace "Id" and "FruitName" while keeping "Currency"?

Yes, I know I can do

```
FruitJson["Id"] = Fruit.Id
FruitJson["FruitName"] = Fruit.FruitName
```

But I feel like there's a better way of doing this since I already have the object. Something along the lines of:

```
dynamic fruitJson = JObject.Parse(json);
Fruit fruit = new Fruit(Id = 1, FruitName = "Orange");
fruitJson.ReplaceOnlyPropertiesThatExistInObject(fruit);
```

And fruitJson should print out

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "FruitName": "Orange",
  "Currency": "USD"
}
```

Every approach I've tried out erases the "Currency" property.

I know there's a JsonSerializer.Populate that partially populates an object with JSON, but I need the other way around.

Comment: And what is wrong with `FruitJson["Id"] = Fruit.Id`? I would argue that it looks just fine.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. But in my case, I need to do this for at least 50 other objects and doing this kind of replacement manually would be a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems that you are using Newtonsoft's Json.NET then you can just use [`Merge`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm) it provides:

```cs
var o1 = JObject.Parse(
"""
{
  "Id": 1,
  "FruitName": "Apple",
  "Currency": "USD"
}
"""
);

var o2 = JObject.FromObject(new Fruit
{
    FruitName = "Clean Apple",
    Id = 2
});

o1.Merge(o2, new JsonMergeSettings
{
    // union array values together to avoid duplicates
    MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union,
});

Console.WriteLine(o1.ToString());
```

Prints:

```json
{
  "Id": 2,
  "FruitName": "Clean Apple",
  "Currency": "USD"
}
```